# how to connect uvc camera with agora video call

Tags: android-studio, agora.io, uvcvideo

- i am tried to stream video from uvc camera with agora video call api. but it doesn't work . but the uvc camera preview show proferly on '''''' .

  public class VideoChatViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CameraDialog.CameraDialogParent, CameraViewInterface.Callback{
  private static final String TAG = VideoChatViewActivity.class.getSimpleName();

  ```
    private static final int PERMISSION_REQ_ID = 22;

    // Permission WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is not mandatory
    // for Agora RTC SDK, just in case if you wanna save
    // logs to external sdcard.
    private static final String[] REQUESTED_PERMISSIONS = {
            Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA
    };

    private RtcEngine mRtcEngine;
    private boolean mCallEnd;
    private boolean mMuted;

    private FrameLayout mLocalContainer;
    private RelativeLayout mRemoteContainer;
    private VideoCanvas mLocalVideo;
    private VideoCanvas mRemoteVideo;

    private ImageView mCallBtn;
    private ImageView mMuteBtn;
    private ImageView mSwitchCameraBtn;

    // Customized logger view
    private LoggerRecyclerView mLogView;

    private final IRtcEngineEventHandler mRtcEventHandler = new IRtcEngineEventHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onJoinChannelSuccess(String channel, final int uid, int elapsed) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mLogView.logI("Join channel success, uid: " + (uid & 0xFFFFFFFFL));
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onUserJoined(final int uid, int elapsed) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mLogView.logI("First remote video decoded, uid: " + (uid & 0xFFFFFFFFL));
                    setupRemoteVideo(uid);
                }
            });
        }


        @Override
        public void onUserOffline(final int uid, int reason) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mLogView.logI("User offline, uid: " + (uid & 0xFFFFFFFFL));
                    onRemoteUserLeft(uid);
                }
            });
        }
    };

    private void setupRemoteVideo(int uid) {
        ViewGroup parent = mRemoteContainer;
        if (parent.indexOfChild(mLocalVideo.view) > -1) {
            parent = mLocalContainer;
        }

        if (mRemoteVideo != null) {
            return;
        }

              SurfaceView view = RtcEngine.CreateRendererView(getBaseContext());
        view.setZOrderMediaOverlay(parent == mLocalContainer);
        parent.addView(view);
        mRemoteVideo = new VideoCanvas(view, VideoCanvas.RENDER_MODE_HIDDEN, uid);
        // Initializes the video view of a remote user.
        mRtcEngine.setupRemoteVideo(mRemoteVideo);
    }

    private void onRemoteUserLeft(int uid) {
        if (mRemoteVideo != null && mRemoteVideo.uid == uid) {
            removeFromParent(mRemoteVideo);
            // Destroys remote view
            mRemoteVideo = null;
        }
    }



    //usb
    private static final int DEFAULT_CAPTURE_WIDTH = 1280;
    private static final int DEFAULT_CAPTURE_HEIGHT = 720;

    @BindView(R.id.camer_view)
    public View mTextureView;
    private static final String TAG1 = "Debug";
    private UVCCameraHelper mCameraHelper;

    private CameraViewInterface mUVCCameraView;
    private AlertDialog mDialog;

    private boolean isRequest;
    private boolean isPreview;
    private UVCCameraHelper.OnMyDevConnectListener listener = new UVCCameraHelper.OnMyDevConnectListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAttachDev(UsbDevice device) {
            // request open permission
            if (!isRequest) {
                isRequest = true;
                if (mCameraHelper != null) {
                    mCameraHelper.requestPermission(0);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onDettachDev(UsbDevice device) {
            // close camera
            if (isRequest) {
                isRequest = false;
                mCameraHelper.closeCamera();
                showShortMsg(device.getDeviceName() + " is out");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectDev(UsbDevice device, boolean isConnected) {
            if (!isConnected) {
                showShortMsg("fail to connect,please check resolution params");
                isPreview = false;
            } else {
                isPreview = true;
                showShortMsg("connecting");
                // initialize seekbar
                // need to wait UVCCamera initialize over
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(2500);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        Looper.prepare();
                        if(mCameraHelper != null && mCameraHelper.isCameraOpened()) {

                        }
                        Looper.loop();
                    }
                }).start();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onDisConnectDev(UsbDevice device) {
            showShortMsg("disconnecting");
        }
    };
    //usb


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_chat_view);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);//uvc
        initUI();

        mUVCCameraView = (CameraViewInterface) mTextureView;
        mUVCCameraView.setCallback(this);
        //mLocalContainer.setCallback(this);
        mCameraHelper = UVCCameraHelper.getInstance();
        mCameraHelper.setDefaultPreviewSize(1280,720);
        mCameraHelper.initUSBMonitor(this, mUVCCameraView, listener);
        mCameraHelper.setOnPreviewFrameListener(new AbstractUVCCameraHandler.OnPreViewResultListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPreviewResult(byte[] bytes) {
                try {

                    AgoraVideoFrame frame = new AgoraVideoFrame();
                    frame.buf = bytes;
                    frame.format = AgoraVideoFrame.FORMAT_NV21;

                    frame.stride = DEFAULT_CAPTURE_WIDTH;
                    frame.height = DEFAULT_CAPTURE_HEIGHT;

                    frame.timeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis();

                    mRtcEngine.pushExternalVideoFrame(frame);

                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        // Ask for permissions at runtime.
        // This is just an example set of permissions. Other permissions
        // may be needed, and please refer to our online documents.
        if (checkSelfPermission(REQUESTED_PERMISSIONS[0], PERMISSION_REQ_ID) &&
                checkSelfPermission(REQUESTED_PERMISSIONS[1], PERMISSION_REQ_ID)) {
            initEngineAndJoinChannel();


        }
    }














    private void initUI() {
        mLocalContainer = findViewById(R.id.local_video_view_container);
        mRemoteContainer = findViewById(R.id.remote_video_view_container);

        mCallBtn = findViewById(R.id.btn_call);
        mMuteBtn = findViewById(R.id.btn_mute);
        mSwitchCameraBtn = findViewById(R.id.btn_switch_camera);

        mLogView = findViewById(R.id.log_recycler_view);

        // Sample logs are optional.
        showSampleLogs();
    }

    private void showSampleLogs() {
        mLogView.logI("Welcome to Agora 1v1 video call");
        mLogView.logW("You will see custom logs here");
        mLogView.logE("You can also use this to show errors");
    }

    private boolean checkSelfPermission(String permission, int requestCode) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission) !=
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, REQUESTED_PERMISSIONS, requestCode);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == PERMISSION_REQ_ID) {
            if (grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
                    grantResults[1] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
                    grantResults[2] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                showLongToast("Need permissions " + Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO +
                        "/" + Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
                finish();
                return;
            }

            // Here we continue only if all permissions are granted.
            // The permissions can also be granted in the system settings manually.
            initEngineAndJoinChannel();
        }
    }

    private void showLongToast(final String msg) {
        this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }

    private void initEngineAndJoinChannel() {

        initializeEngine();
        setupVideoConfig();
        setupLocalVideo();
        joinChannel();
    }

    private void initializeEngine() {
        try {
            mRtcEngine = RtcEngine.create(getBaseContext(), getString(R.string.agora_app_id), mRtcEventHandler);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, Log.getStackTraceString(e));
            throw new RuntimeException("NEED TO check rtc sdk init fatal error\n" + Log.getStackTraceString(e));
        }
    }

    private void setupVideoConfig() {

        mRtcEngine.enableVideo();


        mRtcEngine.setVideoEncoderConfiguration(new VideoEncoderConfiguration(
                VideoEncoderConfiguration.VD_640x360,
                VideoEncoderConfiguration.FRAME_RATE.FRAME_RATE_FPS_15,
                VideoEncoderConfiguration.STANDARD_BITRATE,
                VideoEncoderConfiguration.ORIENTATION_MODE.ORIENTATION_MODE_FIXED_PORTRAIT));
    }

    private void setupLocalVideo() {
  ```

  .
  SurfaceView view = RtcEngine.CreateRendererView(getBaseContext());
  view.setZOrderMediaOverlay(true);
  mLocalContainer.addView(view);
  mLocalVideo = new VideoCanvas(view, VideoCanvas.RENDER_MODE_HIDDEN, 0);
  mRtcEngine.setupLocalVideo(mLocalVideo);
  }

  ```
    private void joinChannel() {

        String token = getString(R.string.agora_access_token);
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(token) || TextUtils.equals(token, "#YOUR ACCESS TOKEN#")) {
            token = null; // default, no token
        }
        mRtcEngine.joinChannel(token, "streaming", "Extra Optional Data", 0);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (!mCallEnd) {
            leaveChannel();
        }

        RtcEngine.destroy();
    }

    private void leaveChannel() {
        mRtcEngine.leaveChannel();
    }

    public void onLocalAudioMuteClicked(View view) {
        mMuted = !mMuted;
        mRtcEngine.muteLocalAudioStream(mMuted);
        int res = mMuted ? R.drawable.btn_mute : R.drawable.btn_unmute;
        mMuteBtn.setImageResource(res);
    }

    public void onSwitchCameraClicked(View view) {
        mRtcEngine.switchCamera();
    }

    public void onCallClicked(View view) {
        if (mCallEnd) {
            startCall();
            mCallEnd = false;
            mCallBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_endcall);
        } else {
            endCall();
            mCallEnd = true;
            mCallBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_startcall);
        }

        showButtons(!mCallEnd);
    }

    private void startCall() {
        setupLocalVideo();
        joinChannel();
    }

    private void endCall() {
        removeFromParent(mLocalVideo);
        mLocalVideo = null;
        removeFromParent(mRemoteVideo);
        mRemoteVideo = null;
        leaveChannel();
    }

    private void showButtons(boolean show) {
        int visibility = show ? View.VISIBLE : View. SurfaceView view .GONE;
        mMuteBtn.setVisibility(visibility);
        mSwitchCameraBtn.setVisibility(visibility);
    }

    private ViewGroup removeFromParent(VideoCanvas canvas) {
        if (canvas != null) {
            ViewParent parent = canvas.view.getParent();
            if (parent != null) {
                ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup) parent;
                group.removeView(canvas.view);
                return group;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void switchView(VideoCanvas canvas) {
        ViewGroup parent = removeFromParent(canvas);
        if (parent == mLocalContainer) {
            if (canvas.view instanceof SurfaceView) {
                ((SurfaceView) canvas.view).setZOrderMediaOverlay(false);
            }
            mRemoteContainer.addView(canvas.view);
        } else if (parent == mRemoteContainer) {
            if (canvas.view instanceof SurfaceView) {
                ((SurfaceView) canvas.view).setZOrderMediaOverlay(true);
            }
            mLocalContainer.addView(canvas.view);
        }
    }

    public void onLocalContainerClick(View view) {
        switchView(mLocalVideo);
        switchView(mRemoteVideo);
    }


    ///uvc

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // step.2 register USB event broadcast
        if (mCameraHelper != null) {
            mCameraHelper.registerUSB();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        // step.3 unregister USB event broadcast
        if (mCameraHelper != null) {
            mCameraHelper.unregisterUSB();
        }
    }



    private void showShortMsg(String msg) {
        //
        Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }




    @Override
    public USBMonitor getUSBMonitor(){   return mCameraHelper.getUSBMonitor();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDialogResult(boolean canceled) {
        if (canceled) {
            showShortMsg("cancel");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(CameraViewInterface cameraViewInterface, Surface surface) {
        if (!isPreview && mCameraHelper.isCameraOpened()) {
            mCameraHelper.startPreview(mUVCCameraView);
            isPreview = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(CameraViewInterface cameraViewInterface, Surface surface, int i, int i1) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceDestroy(CameraViewInterface cameraViewInterface, Surface surface) {
        if (isPreview && mCameraHelper.isCameraOpened()) {
            mCameraHelper.stopPreview();
            isPreview = false;
        }
    }
  ```

  }

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_chat_view);
    initUI();



    // Ask for permissions at runtime.
    // This is just an example set of permissions. Other permissions
    // may be needed, and please refer to our online documents.
    if (checkSelfPermission(REQUESTED_PERMISSIONS[0], PERMISSION_REQ_ID) &&
            checkSelfPermission(REQUESTED_PERMISSIONS[1], PERMISSION_REQ_ID)) {
        initEngineAndJoinChannel();
    }


    //xiaobing add
    final View view = findViewById(R.id.camera_view);
    mUVCCameraView = (CameraViewInterface)view;
    mUSBMonitor = new USBMonitor(this, mOnDeviceConnectListener);
    mUVCCameraView.setAspectRatio(previewWidth / (float)previewHeight);
    mCameraHandler = UVCCameraHandler.createHandler(this,
            mUVCCameraView, previewWidth,
            previewHeight, BANDWIDTH_FACTORS[0],
            firstDataCallBack);


}
//xiaobing add
private void startPreview() {
    final SurfaceTexture st = mUVCCameraView.getSurfaceTexture();
    mCameraHandler.startPreview(new Surface(st));



}
//xiaobing add
UvcCameraDataCallBack firstDataCallBack = new UvcCameraDataCallBack() {
    @Override
    public void getData(byte[] data) {
        if (DEBUG) {
            Log.v(TAG, "data callback:" + data.length);
        }
        AgoraVideoFrame frame = new AgoraVideoFrame();
        frame.buf = data;
        frame.format = AgoraVideoFrame.FORMAT_NV12;

        frame.stride = previewWidth;
        frame.height = previewHeight;

        frame.timeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis();

        mRtcEngine.pushExternalVideoFrame(frame);

    }
};
//xiaobing add
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (DEBUG) Log.v(TAG, "onStart:");
    mUSBMonitor.register();
    if (mUVCCameraView != null)
        mUVCCameraView.onResume();
    if (!mCameraHandler.isOpened()) {

        UsbManager um = (UsbManager) (getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE));
        HashMap<String, UsbDevice> map = um.getDeviceList();
        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
        final ArrayList<UsbDevice> devices = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Map.Entry<String, UsbDevice> item : map.entrySet()) {
            String name = item.getValue().getProductName();
            String vid = Integer.toHexString(item.getValue().getVendorId());
            String pid = Integer.toHexString(item.getValue().getProductId());
            String all = "" + name + " VID:" + vid
                    + " PID:" + pid;
            Log.v("xiaobing", "all:" + all);
            names.add(all);
            devices.add(item.getValue());
            if(item.getValue().getProductId()==1383 && (item.getValue().getVendorId() == 3034)){
                mDev = item.getValue();
                mUSBMonitor.requestPermission(mDev);

                //为了同时支持手机和眼镜，只有获得了眼镜的设备才选择本地视频
                mRtcEngine.setExternalVideoSource(true, true, true);
                mLogView.logI("使用USB摄像头！");


                break;
            }
        }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).